# How do I display an image on success in parsley.js?

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I already have parsley.js integrated with the forms on my website, but I'm trying to take it a step further and display an image (a green checkmark) to display next to each field on success.

This seems like a pretty simple question, but unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to do this by following the parsley.js documentation.

I'm guessing I would just create a div with the image positioned exactly where I want it and do 'display: none' and then change the display to block or something on success? Even what I just described I'm not sure how to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081887/display-loading-gif-after-parsley-js-validates-form

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to a CSS file linked to the webpage

```css
input.parsley-success,
select.parsley-success,
textarea.parsley-success {
   color: #468847;
   border: 1px solid rgba(80, 210, 80, 1);
}

input.parsley-error,
select.parsley-error,
textarea.parsley-error {
 color: white;
 background-color: rgba(255, 30, 30, 0.235);
 border: 1px solid #F56969;
 outline:none;
}

.parsley-errors-list {
  margin: 4px 0 3px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0;
 font-family:Arial;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  color:black;
}

.parsley-errors-list.filled {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In the "input.parsley.select" properties, add:

```css
background: url("link/to/image.jpg") 100px no-repeat;
```

The "100px" may differ depending on the size of the input.

If you want to add green color, then you would add this AFTER the line that sets the image

```css
background-color: rgba(80, 210, 80, 0.35);
```

To do it for elements that are not correct, you would do pretty much the same but for "input.parsley-error".

With this CSS you can also change a few other things like the font for the errors, the list-type, and text color. I suggest you play with that a bit until you get something you like.

Hope I helped!

Comment: The problem with this is the checkmark goes inside of the textfields, I am actually trying to position the image on the right side, but OUTSIDE of the actual text field.