# Unable to display GIF while submitting form after parsley validation

Tags: gif, parsley.js

I want to display GIF on form submitting after parsley is a success, so the condition  is only after submitting form field and validation in the success I need to show `gif` **only when the form is submitting**

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#adform').parsley({
              trigger: 'change',
              successClass: "is-valid",
              errorClass: "is-invalid text-danger",
              errorsWrapper: '<div class="input-group"></div>',
              errorTemplate: '<small class="form-text text-danger"></small>',
     });
 })
       .submit('form:submit', function () {
            $("#subloa").css("display", "block");
        });
```

but doesn't trigger validation.

so how do I show GIF in parsley?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#adform').parsley({
              trigger: 'change',
              successClass: "is-valid",
              errorClass: "is-invalid text-danger",
              errorsWrapper: '<div class="input-group"></div>',
              errorTemplate: '<small class="form-text text-danger"></small>',
     })
       .on('form:submit', function () {
            $("#subloa").css("display", "block");
        });
});
```